# How to unittest local variable in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I need to write a test that will check a local variable value inside a static function. I went through all the `unittest` docs but found nothing yet.

Comment: Show us the static function you are going to test. Generally, local variable is local, so it is not supposed to be tested from outside. Anyway, you may add asserts and other testing stuff inside the function, but this is not something one could call unittest.

Comment: *need to write a test that will check a local variable value inside a static function* why? what value does that add?

Comment: Thank you. I realized that it was a quite bad idea at all.

Comment: Just for reference: if your function calls another one and that variable is one of its parameters, you can mock that second function and assert it's called with certain values. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't. Local variables are local to the function and they cannot be accessed from the outside.

But the bigger point is that you shouldn't actually be trying to test the value of a local variable. Functions should be treated as black boxes from the outside. The are given some parameters and they return some values and/or change the external state. Those are the only things you should check for.

Comment: Hey But code coverage shows local variables assignments as missing what for that ?